# Unable to remove a table row after ajax success

Tags: javascript, html-table

In my html-php table:

```
 <tr id="idrow">
                 <td><?php echo $user_id;  ?></td>
                 <td ><?php echo $user_name;  ?></td>
                 <td>
                     <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete " value="Cancella sin id" onclick="deleteFunction(<?php echo $user_id;  ?>)"/>
                 </td>
</tr>
```

there is a button to erase sql row by a ajax call, using the id field.
My problem is on update table after success:

my js code is:

```
function deleteFunction(valor) {

    var $tr = $('#datatable-id').closest('tr'); 
    var id = valor;
    var parametros = {
                  "id"     : id
          };
          console.log(parametros);


          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "deleteTabla.php", 
                data: parametros, 
                success: function(result){

                                  //$("#idrow").remove();
                                  $tr.remove();

                },
                error: function () {
                  console.log('ajax error');
                }

              });
}
```

Using `$("#idrow").remove()`, the first  row is removed, not the button related one.

I suppose the trick is  on `var $tr = $('#datatable-id').closest('tr');`, the reference to tr label?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to erase?

Comment: the html table row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, every row has the same id (idrow). This is your first mistake. Ids have to be unique throughout the whole page. Create the rows with a unique Id and pass it to the function:

```
<tr id="idrow_<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="deleteFunction('<?php echo $user_id; ?>')"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In your function, just do this:

```
function deleteFunction(valor) {
    ...
    $('#idrow_'+valor).remove();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest `tr` to the `#datatable-id` will always be the first row.
If you want to delete a particular row try assigning an id.

```
 <tr id="<?php echo $user_id;?>">
   ....
 </tr>
```

Then in the function:

```
function deleteFunction(valor) {
    var $tr = $('#' + valor);
    // delete after request is success
   $tr.remove()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr id="idrow_<?= $user_id ?>">
```

And on success:

```
$("#idrow_" + valor).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector at the beginning of the function to this: `var $try = $("#idrow")`